# DirectShow manual graph memory leaks

Tags: c++, directshow

Here is simple capture and render graph build manualy.
CaptureFilter->SmartTee->(preview)->AviDecompressor->Render
All works well and gets 140Mb while working.
After I Stop the render and Release all filters and IGraphBuilder 50Mb remaining!
Again build same filter - all works but 140+50=190Mb in ram.
After release 100Mb remaining.
And again and again.
I had try SmartPtr, ComPtr, Release() in any imaginable combinations but no effect.
Seems I do something compleetly wrong :(

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <dshow.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#pragma comment(lib, "strmiids")

#define SafeRelease(Com) {if (Com!=nullptr){Com->Release(); Com=nullptr;};};

void GetCaptureSource(std::wstring friendly_name, IBaseFilter** ppCaptureFilter);

void GetPin(IPin** ppPin, IBaseFilter* pFilter, std::string direction_str, std::wstring name_wstr = L"");


int  main()
{

    HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(0);

    //Get Capture Filter
    IBaseFilter* p_CaptureFilter;
    GetCaptureSource(L"USB3.0 Capture Video", &p_CaptureFilter);

    //Get Capture Pin
    IPin* p_CaptureOutPin;
    GetPin(&p_CaptureOutPin, p_CaptureFilter, "out");

    //Get Smart Tee Filter
    IBaseFilter* p_SmartTee;
    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_SmartTee, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_PPV_ARGS(&p_SmartTee));

    //Get Smart Tee Pins
    IPin* p_SmartInputPin;
    GetPin(&p_SmartInputPin, p_SmartTee, "in");
    IPin* p_SmartOutputPin;
    GetPin(&p_SmartOutputPin, p_SmartTee, "out", L"Preview");

    //Get AviDecompressorFilter
    IBaseFilter* p_AviDecompressor;
    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_AVIDec, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_PPV_ARGS(&p_AviDecompressor));

    //Get Avi Decompressor Pins
    IPin* p_AviInputPin;
    GetPin(&p_AviInputPin, p_AviDecompressor, "in");
    IPin* p_AviOutputPin;
    GetPin(&p_AviOutputPin, p_AviDecompressor, "out");

    //Get Video Render Filter
    IBaseFilter* p_VideoRender;
    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_VideoRenderer, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_PPV_ARGS(&p_VideoRender));

    //Get Video Render Pin
    IPin* p_RenderPin;
    GetPin(&p_RenderPin, p_VideoRender, "in");

    // Create the Filter Graph Manager.
    IGraphBuilder* p_GraphBuilder;
    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FilterGraph, 0, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IGraphBuilder, (void**)&p_GraphBuilder);

    //Add Capture Filter
    hr = p_GraphBuilder->AddFilter(p_CaptureFilter, L"CaptureFilter");

    //Add Smart Tee Filter
    hr = p_GraphBuilder->AddFilter(p_SmartTee, L"SmartTee");

    //Add Decompressor Filter
    hr = p_GraphBuilder->AddFilter(p_AviDecompressor, L"Avi Decompressor");

    //Add Video Render Filter
    hr = p_GraphBuilder->AddFilter(p_VideoRender, L"Video Render");

    //Connect Pins
    hr = p_GraphBuilder->Connect(p_CaptureOutPin, p_SmartInputPin);
    hr = p_GraphBuilder->Connect(p_SmartOutputPin, p_AviInputPin);
    hr = p_GraphBuilder->Connect(p_AviOutputPin, p_RenderPin);

    //Get Interfaces
    IVideoWindow* p_VideoWindow;
    hr = p_GraphBuilder->QueryInterface(IID_IVideoWindow, (void **)&p_VideoWindow);
    IMediaControl* p_MediaControl;
    hr = p_GraphBuilder->QueryInterface(IID_IMediaControl, (void **)&p_MediaControl);

    //Release all pins references
    SafeRelease(p_CaptureOutPin);
    SafeRelease(p_SmartInputPin);
    SafeRelease(p_SmartOutputPin);
    SafeRelease(p_AviInputPin);
    SafeRelease(p_AviOutputPin);
    SafeRelease(p_RenderPin);

    //Release all filter references
    SafeRelease(p_CaptureFilter);
    SafeRelease(p_SmartTee);
    SafeRelease(p_AviDecompressor);
    SafeRelease(p_VideoRender);

    std::cout << "Press any key to START\n";
    std::system("pause");
    hr = p_MediaControl->Run();

    p_VideoWindow->put_Caption(L"render_window");
    p_VideoWindow->SetWindowPosition(20, 20, 1920, 1080);

    LONG lStyle = GetWindowLong(0, GWL_STYLE);
    lStyle &= ~(WS_CAPTION | WS_THICKFRAME | WS_MINIMIZE | WS_MAXIMIZE | WS_SYSMENU);
    p_VideoWindow->put_WindowStyle(lStyle);

    //There Window apears and ALL GOOD
    std::cout << "Press any key to STOP\n";
    std::system("pause");


    hr = p_MediaControl->Stop();

    hr = p_VideoWindow->put_Visible(OAFALSE);
    hr = p_VideoWindow->put_Owner(NULL);

    //SafeRelease(p_MediaControl);
    //SafeRelease(p_VideoWindow);
    SafeRelease(p_GraphBuilder);

    CoUninitialize();

    std::cout << "Press any key to QUIT\n";
    std::system("pause");
    std::cout << "\n\n";
    //system("pause");
    return 0;


}



void GetCaptureSource(std::wstring friendly_name, IBaseFilter** ppCaptureFilter) {

    HRESULT hr;

    ICreateDevEnum* devs;
    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_SystemDeviceEnum, 0, CLSCTX_INPROC, IID_ICreateDevEnum, (void **)&devs);

    IEnumMoniker* p_InputMonikersEnum;
    hr = devs->CreateClassEnumerator(CLSID_VideoInputDeviceCategory, &p_InputMonikersEnum, 0);
    SafeRelease(devs);


    bool is_capture_finded = false;
    do {
        IMoniker* p_CaptureMoniker;
        hr = p_InputMonikersEnum->Next(1, &p_CaptureMoniker, 0);
        if (hr != S_OK) break;
        IPropertyBag* p_PropBag;
        hr = p_CaptureMoniker->BindToStorage(0, 0, IID_IPropertyBag, (void**)&p_PropBag);
        VARIANT var;
        VariantInit(&var);
        VariantClear(&var);
        hr = p_PropBag->Read(L"FriendlyName", &var, 0);
        SafeRelease(p_PropBag);
        std::wstring input_moniker_friendly_name = std::wstring(var.bstrVal);
        if (input_moniker_friendly_name == friendly_name) {
            is_capture_finded = true;
            hr = p_CaptureMoniker->BindToObject(0, 0, IID_IBaseFilter, (void**)ppCaptureFilter);
            SafeRelease(p_CaptureMoniker);
            break;
        }
        SafeRelease(p_CaptureMoniker);
    } while (true);
    if (is_capture_finded == false) MessageBoxW(0, L"Capture NOT founded.", L"ERROR", MB_OK);

    SafeRelease(p_InputMonikersEnum);

    return;
}


void GetPin(IPin** ppPin, IBaseFilter* pFilter, std::string direction_str, std::wstring name_wstr) {

    HRESULT hr;
    IEnumPins* pEnumPins;
    hr = pFilter->EnumPins(&pEnumPins);
    do {
        IPin* pNextPin;
        hr = pEnumPins->Next(1, &pNextPin, 0);
        if (hr != S_OK) break;
        PIN_INFO pin_inf;
        hr = pNextPin->QueryPinInfo(&pin_inf);
        bool is_pin_of_interest = true;
        if ((direction_str == "in") && (pin_inf.dir == PINDIR_OUTPUT)) is_pin_of_interest = false;
        if ((direction_str == "out") && (pin_inf.dir == PINDIR_INPUT)) is_pin_of_interest = false;
        if ((name_wstr != L"") && (name_wstr != std::wstring(pin_inf.achName))) is_pin_of_interest = false;
        if (is_pin_of_interest) {
            *ppPin = pNextPin;
            SafeRelease(pNextPin);
            break;
        }
        SafeRelease(pNextPin);
    } while (true);
    SafeRelease(pEnumPins);
    return;
}
```

Comment: But you did not free `p_MediaControl` or `p_VideoWindow`...? Those also point into the graph. It is probably also a good idea to enumerate all remaining filters in the graph and remove them. (`EnumFilters` and `RemoveFilter`)

Comment: If you still have reference leaks after that, start investigating the output of all your `->Release` calls at shutdown time. If that returns 0, the object was removed.

Comment: Release() function on pins returns from 4 to 8.
on filters from 4 to 6
And if do pMediaContrtol->Release();
pVideoWindow->Release();
pGraphBuilder->Relise() <== There ERROR appears;
So why I decide that I am doing somthing wery wrong. And think it is mutch earlier than end section of code. May be my stupid function GetPin.

Comment: The `PIN_INFO` filled in by `GetPin` contains a reference to a filter that you also need to release.

Comment: Solwed.<br/>
1. As Botje says SafeRelease(pin_inf.pFilter);<br/>
2. I should NOT Release IPins when build the graph<br/>
3. Manualy or in cicle remove IFilters from graph. (pGraphBuilder->Release() is NOT enougf)<br/>

And All works perfect!!!!

Comment: Also not need to release pVideoWindow and pMediaContrtol (errors ocuped)

Comment: @nefton - it would be great if you would take the time to actually post an answer to your question rather than just the comments on here so others could benefit.  People don't always read the comments..

Answer (score 1):

That is working code
1. You should relese all I* instanses you had created, but only NOT IPIns
2. See code, there are some other nuance

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <dshow.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#pragma comment(lib, "strmiids")

#define SafeRelease(Com) {if (Com!=nullptr){Com->Release(); Com=nullptr;};};

void GetCaptureSource(std::wstring friendly_name, IBaseFilter** ppCaptureFilter);

void GetPin(IPin** ppPin, IBaseFilter* pFilter, std::string direction_str, std::wstring name_wstr = L"");


int  main()
{

    HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(0);

    //Get Capture Filter
    IBaseFilter* p_CaptureFilter;
    GetCaptureSource(L"USB3.0 Capture Video", &p_CaptureFilter);

    //Get Capture Pin
    IPin* p_CaptureOutPin;
    GetPin(&p_CaptureOutPin, p_CaptureFilter, "out");

    //Get Smart Tee Filter
    IBaseFilter* p_SmartTee;
    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_SmartTee, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_PPV_ARGS(&p_SmartTee));

    //Get Smart Tee Pins
    IPin* p_SmartInputPin;
    GetPin(&p_SmartInputPin, p_SmartTee, "in");
    IPin* p_SmartOutputPin;
    GetPin(&p_SmartOutputPin, p_SmartTee, "out", L"Preview");

    //Get AviDecompressorFilter
    IBaseFilter* p_AviDecompressor;
    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_AVIDec, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_PPV_ARGS(&p_AviDecompressor));

    //Get Avi Decompressor Pins
    IPin* p_AviInputPin;
    GetPin(&p_AviInputPin, p_AviDecompressor, "in");
    IPin* p_AviOutputPin;
    GetPin(&p_AviOutputPin, p_AviDecompressor, "out");

    //Get Video Render Filter
    IBaseFilter* p_VideoRender;
    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_VideoRenderer, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_PPV_ARGS(&p_VideoRender));

    //Get Video Render Pin
    IPin* p_RenderPin;
    GetPin(&p_RenderPin, p_VideoRender, "in");

    // Create the Filter Graph Manager.
    IGraphBuilder* p_GraphBuilder;
    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FilterGraph, 0, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IGraphBuilder, (void**)&p_GraphBuilder);

    //Add Capture Filter
    hr = p_GraphBuilder->AddFilter(p_CaptureFilter, L"CaptureFilter");

    //Add Smart Tee Filter
    hr = p_GraphBuilder->AddFilter(p_SmartTee, L"SmartTee");

    //Add Decompressor Filter
    hr = p_GraphBuilder->AddFilter(p_AviDecompressor, L"Avi Decompressor");

    //Add Video Render Filter
    hr = p_GraphBuilder->AddFilter(p_VideoRender, L"Video Render");

    //Connect Pins
    hr = p_GraphBuilder->Connect(p_CaptureOutPin, p_SmartInputPin);
    hr = p_GraphBuilder->Connect(p_SmartOutputPin, p_AviInputPin);
    hr = p_GraphBuilder->Connect(p_AviOutputPin, p_RenderPin);

    //Get Interfaces
    IVideoWindow* p_VideoWindow;
    hr = p_GraphBuilder->QueryInterface(IID_IVideoWindow, (void **)&p_VideoWindow);
    IMediaControl* p_MediaControl;
    hr = p_GraphBuilder->QueryInterface(IID_IMediaControl, (void **)&p_MediaControl);

    //DONT RELEASE IPINS REFERENSES!!!!!!!!
    //IT CAUSE ERROR WHEN YOU TRY TO RELEASE FILTERS OR GRAPH WERY LATER
    //AND WILL BE WERY HARD TO FIND IT

    //p_CaptureOutPin->Release();
    //p_SmartInputPin->Release();
    //p_SmartOutputPin->Release();
    //p_AviInputPin->Release(); 
    //p_AviOutputPin->Release();
    //p_RenderPin->Release(); 

    //Release all filter references
    p_CaptureFilter->Release();
    p_SmartTee->Release();
    p_AviDecompressor->Release();
    p_VideoRender->Release();

    std::cout << "Press any key to START\n";
    std::system("pause");
    hr = p_MediaControl->Run();

    p_VideoWindow->put_Caption(L"render_window");
    p_VideoWindow->SetWindowPosition(20, 20, 1920, 1080);

    LONG lStyle = GetWindowLong(0, GWL_STYLE);
    lStyle &= ~(WS_CAPTION | WS_THICKFRAME | WS_MINIMIZE | WS_MAXIMIZE | WS_SYSMENU);
    p_VideoWindow->put_WindowStyle(lStyle);

    //There Window apears and ALL GOOD
    std::cout << "Press any key to STOP\n";
    std::system("pause");


    hr = p_MediaControl->Stop();

    hr = p_VideoWindow->put_Visible(OAFALSE);
    hr = p_VideoWindow->put_Owner(NULL);

    // Enumerate the filters in the graph.
    IEnumFilters *pEnum = NULL;
    hr = p_GraphBuilder->EnumFilters(&pEnum);
    do {
        IBaseFilter *pFilter = NULL;
        hr = pEnum->Next(1, &pFilter, NULL);
        if (hr != S_OK) break;
        // Remove the filter.
        p_GraphBuilder->RemoveFilter(pFilter);
        // RESET THE ENUMERATOR IN CYCLE (WERY STRANGE CODE BUT ELSEWERE NOTHING WORKS)
        pEnum->Reset();
        pFilter->Release();
    } while (true);
    pEnum->Release();


    std::cout << "Press any key to QUIT\n";
    std::system("pause");
    std::cout << "\n\n";
    //system("pause");
    return 0;


}



void GetCaptureSource(std::wstring friendly_name, IBaseFilter** ppCaptureFilter) {

    HRESULT hr;

    ICreateDevEnum* devs;
    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_SystemDeviceEnum, 0, CLSCTX_INPROC, IID_ICreateDevEnum, (void **)&devs);

    IEnumMoniker* p_InputMonikersEnum;
    hr = devs->CreateClassEnumerator(CLSID_VideoInputDeviceCategory, &p_InputMonikersEnum, 0);
    SafeRelease(devs);


    bool is_capture_finded = false;
    do {
        IMoniker* p_CaptureMoniker;
        hr = p_InputMonikersEnum->Next(1, &p_CaptureMoniker, 0);
        if (hr != S_OK) break;
        IPropertyBag* p_PropBag;
        hr = p_CaptureMoniker->BindToStorage(0, 0, IID_IPropertyBag, (void**)&p_PropBag);
        VARIANT var;
        VariantInit(&var);
        VariantClear(&var);
        hr = p_PropBag->Read(L"FriendlyName", &var, 0);
        SafeRelease(p_PropBag);
        std::wstring input_moniker_friendly_name = std::wstring(var.bstrVal);
        if (input_moniker_friendly_name == friendly_name) {
            is_capture_finded = true;
            hr = p_CaptureMoniker->BindToObject(0, 0, IID_IBaseFilter, (void**)ppCaptureFilter);
            SafeRelease(p_CaptureMoniker);
            break;
        }
        SafeRelease(p_CaptureMoniker);
    } while (true);
    if (is_capture_finded == false) MessageBoxW(0, L"Capture NOT founded.", L"ERROR", MB_OK);

    SafeRelease(p_InputMonikersEnum);

    return;
}


void GetPin(IPin** ppPin, IBaseFilter* pFilter, std::string direction_str, std::wstring name_wstr) {

    HRESULT hr;
    IEnumPins* pEnumPins;
    hr = pFilter->EnumPins(&pEnumPins);
    do {
        IPin* pNextPin;
        hr = pEnumPins->Next(1, &pNextPin, 0);
        if (hr != S_OK) break;
        PIN_INFO pin_inf;
        hr = pNextPin->QueryPinInfo(&pin_inf);
        bool is_pin_of_interest = true;
        if ((direction_str == "in") && (pin_inf.dir == PINDIR_OUTPUT)) is_pin_of_interest = false;
        if ((direction_str == "out") && (pin_inf.dir == PINDIR_INPUT)) is_pin_of_interest = false;
        if ((name_wstr != L"") && (name_wstr != std::wstring(pin_inf.achName))) is_pin_of_interest = false;
        pin_inf.pFilter->Release();
        if (is_pin_of_interest) {
            *ppPin = pNextPin;
            SafeRelease(pNextPin);
            break;
        }
        SafeRelease(pNextPin);
    } while (true);
    SafeRelease(pEnumPins);
    return;
}
```

Comment: Also `p_VideoWindow` needs to be freed. But anyway there are some leaks, at least handle leaks. I ran the code in cycle 100 times and task manager shows that handle count is growing. Deleaker shows leaks of mutexes, events etc., here the screenshot https://i.snag.gy/OIhCub.jpg